# ASP.NET MVC - Database View as DbSet?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having a hard time connecting to an existing view in the database.
I've created the model and now I'm trying to add the DbSet to my existing context so I can query it.

I've tried the following, but every time I create a new EF migration, it tries to create the object as a table in the database.

```
public DbSet<SurveyResponse> SurveyResponses { get; set; }
```

I tried the same declaration as an IQueryable which seemed to stop the creation of the table, but when I tried to access context.SurveyResponses, SurveyResponses was showing no data.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried add-migration name -ignorechanges it should stop EF from trying to create the table

Comment: @heymega - that worked, thanks!
I'm wondering if there's a way to force EF to consider this as a view though so I don't have to ignore the changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop EF creating the tables you can specify the ignore changes flag when adding a migration.

```
add-migration name -ignorechanges
```

Entity Framework treats the view mappings the same as table mappings.

Just remember not to update the view entity otherwise you will get an error!